# $_GET and URL parameters and check for sent value

Tags: php, html, parameters, get

I got two links with a parameter with a value. When I click either link it will send me to the same challenge.php page, I'm wanting to find the value of the parameter and display the page according to what value the parameter has in the URL.
This script doesn't seem to be working.

```
<a href="http://www.site.com/challenge.php?id=1">Complete Challenge 1</a>
<a href="http://www.site.com/challenge.php?id=2">Complete Challenge 2</a>


$id = $_GET['id'];
if ($id=1) {
        echo "This is challenge 1 completed";
} elseif ($id=2) {
    echo "This is challenge 2 completed";
 else {
    echo "The URL parameters didn't work";
}
```

Comment: = should be == just to be conditional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing two values, use the comparison operator == not the assignment operator =. Your code should looks like this.

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];

if ($id == 1) {
        echo "This is challenge 1 completed";
} elseif ($id == 2) {
    echo "This is challenge 2 completed";
 else {
    echo "The URL parameters didn't work";
}
```

Comment: if you (int) before, you could also use === then.

Answer (score 1):

you are using `=` instead of `==` in conditions

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
if (1 == $id) {  // you can use === if you want to compare type also
        echo "This is challenge 1 completed";
} elseif (2 == $id) {
    echo "This is challenge 2 completed";
 else {
    echo "The URL parameters didn't work";
}
```

In condition if you use `1 == $id` it will save from making mistakes of  `$id = 1`.
In case if you write `1 = $id` it will give error

Answer (score 1):

and what if you try `if ($id == 1)` ? :)
'==' is a boolean operator, but I think you know that.

Answer (score 0):

Use $id==1 else you make $id 1.

== looks if it is equal, = makes the left variable the right value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, cast `$_GET` value to int:

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
```

In your conditions you are assigning values to the `$id` variable:

```
$id = 1
```

There is mistake, you should compare it to the numbers:

```
$id == 1
```

So it should look like:

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
if ($id == 1) {
        echo "This is challenge 1 completed";
} elseif ($id == 2) {
    echo "This is challenge 2 completed";
 else {
    echo "The URL parameters didn't work";
}
```